# Corona SDK - display.newImageRect is not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have relatively simple but stupid question, but surprisingly could not find solution :(
I am new to Corona SDK and trying to display an image. All images are place in directory `images` directory relative to `main.lua`.
Presently i am doing like this

```
local IMAGE_DIR = "images";
local bg = display.newImageRect( IMAGE_DIR.. "/bg.png", 570, 360 )
mainScreenGroup:insert(bg)
```

and it is working perfectly. But according to documentation, here is the syntax

```
display.newImageRect( [parentGroup,] filename, [baseDirectory] width, height )
```

i have found that instead of concatenate `IMAGE_DIR`, i can specify `[baseDirectory]` and instead of manually inserting into group `mainScreenGroup`, i can specify `[parentGroup,]` all in one line. But i am not being able to make it work. I have tried following.

```
local bg = display.newImageRect( [mainScreenGroup,] "bg.png", [IMAGE_DIR] 570, 360 )
local bg = display.newImageRect( [mainScreenGroup], "bg.png", [IMAGE_DIR], 570, 360 )
local bg = display.newImageRect( [mainScreenGroup], "/bg.png", [IMAGE_DIR], 570, 360 )
local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, "/bg.png", IMAGE_DIR, 570, 360 )
local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, "bg.png", IMAGE_DIR, 570, 360 )
```

But nothing of the above 5 statements working. Am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, "bg.png", IMAGE_DIR, 570, 360 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use IMAGE_DIR as your baseDirectory, it has to be one of 4 mentioned in the docs [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/pathForFile.html) and [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html):

- system.CachesDirectory
- system.DocumentsDirectory
- system.ResourceDirectory
- system.TemporaryDirectory

In your case, you will still need to append IMAGE_DIR, but you can get rid of inserting bg to group, so your code:

```
local IMAGE_DIR = "images/";
local bg = display.newImageRect( IMAGE_DIR.. "/bg.png", 570, 360 )
mainScreenGroup:insert(bg)
```

can be changed to:

```
local IMAGE_DIR = "images/";
local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, IMAGE_DIR.."/bg.png", 570, 360 )
```

As mentioned by Teddy Engel, you need to be careful if you want to use system.ResourceDirectory on Android - see [docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

The baseDirectory parameter cannot be just any value, you can only fill it with values mentionned here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/pathForFile.html

From the newImageRect doc:

> baseDirectory (optional)
>
> Constant. Path to load the image data from
> filename. Default is system.ResourceDirectory (project folder; same
> location as main.lua). See system.pathForFile() for valid values).

So in your initial example, what the project would do is look for the system.ResourceDirectory/images/bg.png (system.ResourceDirectory being the same folder as the one where your main.lua is).

If it still doesn't show, check the gotchas on newImageRect to make sure your image can load.

Also, for Android you cannot rely on using system.ResourceDirectory:

> Android
>
> File access in Corona is based on the underlining operating system
> which varies by platform. On iOS devices, you can access files in all
> of the directories described above. On Android, however, there is no
> literal system.ResourceDirectory because all resource files reside
> inside a compressed APK file.
>
> Corona allows direct loading of images and audio files using the
> appropriate APIs, but it has limited access to resource files on
> Android using the file I/O APIs. Specifically, the following types can
> not be read from the resources directory: .html, .htm., .3gp, .m4v,
> .mp4, .png, .jpg, and .ttf.
>
> Because of this limitation, if you have files of these types bundled
> in the core directory that you need to copy to another directory, you
> must change the file name so it can be accessed by the file I/O APIs.
> For example, if you want to move cat.png from the resource directory
> to the documents directory, it must be renamed cat.png.txt to be
> copied. See http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

In your last example you should not have "/" before the file name `bg.png`.

```
local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, "bg.png", IMAGE_DIR, 570, 360 )
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have tried this, but unfortunately its not working too. I am now editing my question to include this.

Comment: Okay. Have you made sure that you have a display group named mainScreenGroup and that the string IMAGE_DIR is not nil?

Comment: Try these prints and see if they give you a string and a table:
print("Directory:",IMAGE_DIR)
print("Display group:",mainScreenGroup)

Comment: Here is the output of print statement. Directory: images, Display group: table: 0x10e2225e0. And i am sure these two are not nill, coz i am just replacing the line that is working perfect, with the line you suggested.

Comment: Hmm, I see.. try to replace your display group with self.view. Maybe you forgot to add your display group to the screen. local group = self.view; group:insert(mainScreenGroup);

Comment: self.view is crashing the app, i think its available with Storyboard, i am using Director class, not storyboard

Comment: If i use local bg = display.newImageRect( mainScreenGroup, "bg.png", IMAGE_DIR, 570, 360 ), and print "bg" it is nil.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Im not familiar so much with Director class. 
If "bg" is nil, it means he can't find the image. So, make sure the image is named "bg.png" (and not of any other image types), it is placed under the "images" directory relative to main.lua. Also, the non-retina size of that image should be of size 570 width and 360 height. If it still does not work, we have a serious problem :)

Comment: Thanks @Pontus, for your time, i have double check everything is seems to be perfect but still image not displaying. I'll look at it more on internet, Thanks again.